# Registering listener issue

Tags: android, networking, gps, location, timertask

I've been working on a location service for a demo application. I'm setting up a listener for network and GPS (I know this can be done with one but Ive very basic java and find this easier to work with). Anyway i want to register for GPS updates and start a timer if i get a fix i want to restart the timer and carry on listening. However if the timer goes off i want to register for network updates.

The problem so far is when the timer elapses and I try to register for network updates in run() of my timerTask using mLocationM.request .... I get an exception.

I figure this is a thread issue and am looking for the most basic way around it trying to avoid getting heavy into handler.

```
class GpsTimer extends TimerTask{

    @Override
    public void run() {

        Log.d(TAG, "running");

        mLocationM.requestLocationUpdates
            (LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 2 * 60 * 1000, 0, mNetworkListener);


    }

}
```

I figure thats the line causing the problem

```
03-17 16:33:38.528: E/AndroidRuntime(29913): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-1364
03-17 16:33:38.528: E/AndroidRuntime(29913): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
03-17 16:33:38.528: E/AndroidRuntime(29913):    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
03-17 16:33:38.528: E/AndroidRuntime(29913):    at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.<init>(LocationManager.java:183)
03-17 16:33:38.528: E/AndroidRuntime(29913):    at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.<init>(LocationManager.java:183)
03-17 16:33:38.528: E/AndroidRuntime(29913):    at android.location.LocationManager._requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:661)
03-17 16:33:38.528: E/AndroidRuntime(29913):    at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:486)
03-17 16:33:38.528: E/AndroidRuntime(29913):    at com.sblyit.finder.LocationService$GpsTimer$1.run(LocationService.java:150)
03-17 16:33:38.528: E/AndroidRuntime(29913):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: Exception, please? Thread looper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
class GpsTimer extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        Looper.prepare();
        Log.d("", "running");

        mLocationM.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                2 * 60 * 1000, 0, mNetworkListener);

        Looper.loop();

    }

}
```

Why should not use `handler`

```
Handler h = new Handler();

Runnable run = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.d("", "running");

        mLocationM.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                2 * 60 * 1000, 0, mNetworkListener);

        h.postDelayed(this, 5000); // 5 seconds
    }
};

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    h.removeCallbacks(run);
};
```

It works as `TimerTask`

```
    h.post(run);
```

Comment: Thanks Anthon for the edit. Think ill go with the Looper.prepare for now anyway it seems to work fine for my needs. Thanks again sunshine

Comment: okay great. If you have tried my answer (`looper`) then you can select as accepted answer.

Comment: I will do that now tried to give you a up vote but dont have the 15 reputation needed. One more question if i get a fix from GPS I want to restart the timer should I cancel it first??